# Tauri app installs successfully but doesn't run

Tags: node.js, windows, rust, tauri

I'm writing a Tauri app to scrape a web page and provide a user-friendly UI. I've managed to get it to an MVP but there is a problem. Running `yarn tauri build` successfully builds the `.msi` installer. Running the installer also is sucessful and properly installs the app. However upon trying to run it, it does nothing, not even showing an error message or status code.

I attempted to run as administrator and it still didn't work. I thought it might be the `headless_chrome` crate, but removing it and building the app yielded the same result, so I really don't know what to do.

The executable file within `project/src-tauri/target/release` works... unless I move it outside of `project` (I tested it in `project/src-tauri/target`, `project/src-tauri` and `project` and it runs in all of them, but not in `project`'s parent directory.

I'm in windows and the app is for windows machines (as implied by the `.msi` installer) and below is the output of `yarn tauri info`:

```
Environment
  › OS: Windows 10.0.22621 X64
  › Webview2: 113.0.1774.35
  › MSVC:
      - Ferramentas de Build do Visual Studio 2022
  › Node.js: 18.15.0
  › npm: 9.5.0
  › pnpm: Not installed!
  › yarn: 1.22.19
  › rustup: 1.25.2
  › rustc: 1.68.2
  › cargo: 1.68.2
  › Rust toolchain: stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc

Packages
  › @tauri-apps/cli [NPM]: 1.2.3
  › @tauri-apps/api [NPM]: 1.2.0
  › tauri [RUST]: 1.3.0,
  › tauri-build [RUST]: 1.3.0,
  › tao [RUST]: 0.16.0,
  › wry [RUST]: 0.24.1,

App
  › build-type: bundle
  › CSP: unset
  › distDir: ../dist
  › devPath: http://localhost:1420/
  › framework: SolidJS
  › bundler: Vite

App directory structure
  ├─ .git
  ├─ .vscode
  ├─ dist
  ├─ node_modules
  ├─ public
  ├─ src
  └─ src-tauri
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into the same problem and managed to figure it out.

1. The .exe in your release folder isn't meant to work outside your project, that's just there to run from within the project
2. The .msi folder in your bundle folder, that's what you are supposed to use to install the app
3. After installation if you don't see anything other than a .exe file in your installation path, that's because that's all there should be for the app. If you used any additional resources for your frontend, then you need to add those resource paths to your tauri.conf.json file in tauri.bundle.resource . lean how to add the resource paths from here, after doing so if you build again and install you should see your resources in your installation folder
4. And for the error why opening the .exe file does nothing, that's because your app is running into an error even before the tauri::Builder was called in your main.rs file and causing it to crash before opening the app.
5. Now this error could be any error, but in my case, it was because I was trying to create a SQLite database before starting the app, but the path I passed for the database was a referenced path from my .env file, but that path would reference a path that's inside the Program Files directory, which you are not allowed to access, so I changed the path to a absolute path of the user's AppData directory (which you are allowed to access). And that's solved all the issue for me
6. But for you there could be some other error that causing the same issue, so i recommend before creating the release build, create a debug build using the command "cargo tauri build --debug", this will create a debug folder in your target folder. If you install the app from there and run it, it will launch a tarminal with the app that will show all the error (As long as the error is after the app builder runs, if the error is happing before the builder runs then thats the reason your app is not even starting)

Comment: Thanks. My app was also trying to create a SQLite database in the Program Files folder and that was causing the issue. At the time I figured the easiest work around would be to use the nsis installer instead as it installs the app in a folder that doesn't require admin privileges but in the future I will most certainly refer to the AppData folder instead